# How to set Auth token cookie from GraphQL Mutation with Apollo

Tags: reactjs, cookies, graphql, apollo, prisma

I'm using GraphQLServer from graphql-yoga to handle requests. My back-end is able to communicate with my React front-end at this point and I can make graphql queries and get the response just fine.

I was recently informed that I should be setting a cookie with the token, rather than returning it in the mutation response. So I'm trying to switch over but the cookie isn't being set by the mutation.

***server.js*** (node)

```
import { GraphQLServer, PubSub } from 'graphql-yoga';
import {resolvers, fragmentReplacements} from './resolvers/index'
import prisma from './prisma'

const pubsub = new PubSub()

export default new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  context(request) {
    return {
      pubsub,
      prisma,
      request, //fragmentReplacements[], request, response
    }
  },
  fragmentReplacements
});
```

***Mutation.js*** (node)

```
export default {
  async createUser(parent, args, {prisma, request}, info) {
    const lastActive = new Date().toISOString()
    const user = await prisma.mutation.createUser({ data: {...args.data, lastActive }})
    const token = generateToken(user.id)
    const options = {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, //expires in a day
      // httpOnly: true, // cookie is only accessible by the server
      // secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod', // only transferred over https
      // sameSite: true, // only sent for requests to the same FQDN as the domain in the cookie
    }
    const cookie = request.response.cookie('token', token, options)
    console.log(cookie)
    return {user}
  },
  // more mutations...
```

[image: console.log(cookie)]

console.log(cookie) outputs with the cookie attached

***index.js*** (react)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import ApolloClient, { InMemoryCache, create } from 'apollo-boost';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  credentials: 'include',
  request: async operation => {
    operation.setContext({
      fetchOptions: {
        credentials: 'same-origin'
      }
    })
  },
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>, 
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

So my questions are:

1. **Is there a better way to do authentication with GraphQL**, or is setting the token with a cookie in the auth mutation suitable?
2. Assuming it's a decent approach, **how can I set the cookie from the mutation**?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The way that you set the cookie is correct, I have successfully set cookies this way from an Express app. When you say that it is "not set", what do you mean exactly? Is it not visible in the developer console in the UI? Regarding the first question - you can use JWT and return the token as part of the response rather than a cookie. It appears to be the standard authentication/authorisation mechanism in GraphQL, I have managed to implement this successfully in the past.

Comment: Returning the token and using it directly in subsequent requests is not advisable in a browser-based client as it can be stolen by an attacker using JS, whereas cookies set with HTTPOnly and Secure flags cannot be accessed by JS.

Comment: @Jaryl Thanks, went with using the secure same-domain cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the credentials in the ApolloClient

```
 fetchOptions: {
    credentials: 'include'
 }
```